# Dynamic list not showing all elements in a linear layout

Tags: android

I have a horizontal linear layout that is filled with TextViews from a dynamic list, but it doesn't show all elements since it seems to be out of the parent's bounds. What I need is to fill the space below if needed.

Here's my code:

The xml:

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView_serie" android:contentDescription="imatge_serie"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nom_serie"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/nom_serie" android:contentDescription="nom_serie" tools:text="Nom_serie"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView_serie"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize = "16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/any_serie" android:contentDescription="any_serie" tools:text="any_serie"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nom_serie"
    />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sinopsis"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "8dp"
        android:id="@+id/sinopsi_serie" android:contentDescription="sinopsis_serie" tools:text="sinopsis_serie"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/imageView_serie"
        android:layout_below = "@id/nom_serie"
    />
    <RatingBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/ratingbar_serie"
        android:layout_below = "@id/imageView_serie"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Puntuacio"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop = "8dp"
            android:id="@+id/puntuacio" android:contentDescription="puntuacio" tools:text="puntuacio"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ratingbar_serie"
            android:layout_below = "@id/imageView_serie"
    />

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Casting:"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "24dp"
        android:id="@+id/casting" android:contentDescription="casting" tools:text="casting"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/cast" android:contentDescription="cast" tools:text="cast"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/casting"

    />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Direccio:"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop = "24dp"
        android:id="@+id/direccio" android:contentDescription="direccio" tools:text="direccio"
    />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/dir" android:contentDescription="dir" tools:text="dir"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/direccio"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Temporades:"
            android:textSize="24dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:id="@+id/nTemporades" android:contentDescription="nTemporades" tools:text="nTemporades"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Comentaris"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/titol_comentaris_serie" android:contentDescription="titol_comentari_serie" tools:text="titol_comentari_serie"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/panell"
              android:orientation="horizontal">
</LinearLayout>
```

And this how I generate the text views from the list:

```
LinearLayout panell = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panell);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        TextView btn = new TextView(this);
        btn.setId(i);
        final int id_ = btn.getId();
        btn.setText("button " + id_);
        //btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(70, 80, 90));
        panell.addView(btn, params);
        btn = ((TextView) findViewById(id_));
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(view.getContext(),
                        "Button clicked index = " + id_, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here's my : 
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2MVv.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend Google's **flexbox-layout** project: https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

A `FlexboxLayout` (when configured correctly) has the ability to add any number of child `TextView`s in a line (like `LinearLayout` would), but will automatically "wrap" to the next line if a child wouldn't fit.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped me a lot! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Why not try to use a ListView , if u add the same propreties every time